# Can a spellbreaker immune to conjuration be attacked by summoned monsters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, class-feature, magic, summoning

The [spellbreaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/inquisitor-archetypes-paizo/spellbreaker) inquisitor archetype has this nice capstone candy:

> **Impervious (Ex)**
>
> At 20th level, a Spellbreaker becomes immune to the effects of a single school of arcane magic. That school of magic must be the first one she picked for defense against magic (see above). Neither harmful nor helpful arcane spells of that school have an effect on the Spellbreaker. If a spell of that school is an area of effect spell, the spell goes off as normal, but the Spellbreaker is untouched by its effects. Once per day, as a swift action, the Spellbreaker can grant this imperviousness to all allies in a 60-foot burst for 1 minute.
>
> This ability replaces true judgment.

If the school happens to be conjuration, is she immune to attacks from summoned monsters?

Comment: Regardless of the answer, I think I'd allow it on the grounds of the character giving up teleportation...

Comment: @Ifusaso yes, but the worthyness of the choice is useless. Yes, it is a bad choice when one can pick a school with **less useful* personal spells. But if giving up teleportation is a dumb idea is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Hence, not an answer. Just something answers might consider

Answer (score 4):

A [spellbreaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/inquisitor-archetypes-paizo/spellbreaker) [inquisitor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/) that picks for the extraordinary ability impervious the school [conjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Conjuration) is "immune to the effects of" spells of the school conjuration, and, "[i]f a spell of that school is an area of effect spell, the spell goes off as normal, but the Spellbreaker [*sic*] is untouched by its effects."

There no way to know what this *really* means short of asking the author, the archetype spellbreaker even going unmentioned by the [*Ultimate Combat* FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1g1). The GM must make the call.

That is, many spells—including, for example, the [*summon monster*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/) spells—have *Effect* entries (for details see [Aiming a Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell)), but whether or not the level 20 spellbreaker inquisitor should *actually* be immune to *all* these proper *Effects*—whatever *immune* means here—is unknown. So I'm clear, besides its impact on *summon* spells, immunity to spells of the conjuration school raises other questions: Can the spellbreaker inquisitor enter the effect of a [*mage's magnificent mansion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-s-magnificent-mansion/) spell? Can she ride the effect of a [*phantom steed*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantom-steed/) spell? If she throws an acorn grenade that's created by the spell [*fire seeds*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fire-seeds/), does it explode? If a successful [Use Magic Device](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/use-magic-device/) skill check enables her to cast from a wand the spell [*fire shuriken*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fiery-shuriken/), would the spell fail? Read even more broadly, does being "immune to the effects" of spells of the picked school include immunity to ancillary and collateral effects of such spells? Like, if a *house* is swept up by the effect of the spell [*tsunami*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/tsunami/), and the house hits the inquisitor, is the inquisitor untouched *by the house?* (Note that *I* don't need answers to these questions; instead, they are the kind of questions my inner editor would've raised were I to've homebrewed the special ability impervious. I'd've rewritten the special ability so that the answers are, respectively, clearly *Yes*, *Yes*, *Yes*, *No*, *No*, *No*.)

This reader *suspects*—yet can't prove—that the special ability impervious is *supposed* to be like the special ability magic immunity that's possessed by [some](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-iron/) [golems](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/golem/golem-gelatinous-tohc/)—making the special ability impervious, essentially, unbeatable [spell resistance](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Spell-Resistance) that can't be lowered against, in this case, spells of one school of magic—, but, for instance, the special ability impervious grants immunity even to spells of the picked school that possess the entry *Spell Resistance: No*… which is utterly unlike the special ability spell resistance *and* the special ability magic immunity. This makes this reader hesitant to draw parallels, especially since the author of the archetype spellbreaker didn't see fit to either.

#### What this GM would do

First, I'd sit down with the spellbreaker inquisitor's player and have a *very* serious talk about what being immune to spells of the conjuration school means to the player and the campaign. A level 20 PC that can't be affected by spells of the [teleportation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Conjuration-Teleportation) subschool is likely to soon find himself a victim of the vagaries of mundane travel (*yuck!*) and miss out on adventures as the rest of the party [*bamfs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamf) from locale to locale. Similarly, considering the horrible things that routinely happen to high-level PCs, a level 20 PC that can't be affected by spells of the [healing](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Conjuration-Healing) subschool—and that includes, like, [*raise dead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/raise-dead/), by the way—just isn't long for the campaign. (*Headstone Idea:* "She picked conjuration. Whoops.")

Then, if the player *still* refuses to reconsider, we'd negotiate a short list of how the special ability impervious works in the game. At the top of that list, for instance, I'd put that the special ability impervious when applied to spells of the conjuration school prevents attacks by summoned creatures in a way identical to the [*protection from*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-evil/) alignment spells do. Getting a 1st-level spell effect from a level 20 capstone seems reasonable to me. Then the player might propose the whole house thing I mentioned above, and I'd nix that, but I'd rule that the ability didn't affect ongoing effects, so the PC could still toss acorn grenades, ride a *phantom steed* effect, and enter a *mansion* effect. That sort of thing.

Comment: Good headstone!  Ha. I think summoned monsters are ongoing effects the same way phantom steeds are, so I don't see this as consistent... but you're right about the character being so hosed it might be best to throw them any bones available.

Comment: @noneuklid Yeah, I'm imagining a difference between *the effect affecting you* and *you affecting the effect* that I can't articulate better than that right now. It's a little inconsistent, sure, but, yeah, the GM probably won't have to deal with the PC for very long anyway.

Comment: And honestly, what a double-edged capstone. It is like giving your players a +40 Mythos points at the end of the campaign, when only a few sessions are left. And I'll drop this link here for no important reason: http://legendaryquest.netfirms.com/books/RPG_Design_Patterns_9_13_09.pdf

Comment: @Mindwin Yeah, enchantment has *aid* and *heroism*, evocation has *divine power*, illusion has *invisibility* and *displacement*, abjuration has *dispel magic*, divination has *detect magic* ("Yeah, the evil wizard cast a spell on you *and* the spell affected you, but, no, you can't determine out what the spell is"), and conjuration and transmutation have pretty much *everything else*.  Although enchantment comes close, there is no *perfect* choice for this *level 20 character's capstone ability!* If the spellbreaker could raise or lower it like SR, it'd be a thing, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the spellbreaker can be attacked by summoned monsters.  Any spell of the chosen school that targets the spellbreaker or includes her in its area of effect will fail to affect her, but summon monster spells and the like do not have a target.  (Although reasonably we could say that their target is "the monster.")